# Use Stirling's formula to prove probability of the event visits the origin after 2n steps

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

[image]

This is the problem, I have done for case $p = 1/2$. But I have no clue where case $p \neq 1/2.$ Here is my attempt.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) &=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(S_{2n} = 0)\\
                           &=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(4pq)^n}{\sqrt{n \pi}}.
\end{align*}

Do I need to compare this to the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$?, btw I don't know why I'd get the series above is less than $\infty.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can show that if $4pq > 0$ then this series converges iff $4pq < 1$. So then you need to show that that's true.